# Jenkins cannot be stopped from Windows > Services on Windows 10

Tags: jenkins

I'm running Jenkins 2.14 on Win 10.

I have started it as a Windows Service but now it cannot be stopped. When I go to Windows Services, it is showing as running but it cannot be stopped from the context menu.

[image]

Running net start jenkins / net stop jenkins displays the following:
[image]

Running sc queryex jenkins gives the following:

[image]

hitting localhost:8080 shows Jenkins is up but when I select 'Shutdown' from the webpage, it never shuts down!

Confused - anyone shed any light?

Comment: I should add, I want the ability to run it both as a service and from command line on demand

Answer (score 0):

now working in latest Jenkins 2.14